# Getting Issue in implementing Cross platform gplus oauth2

Tags: php, android, oauth-2.0, cross-platform, google-oauth

We are implementing cross platform (Android, PHP) gplus oauth2 for user authentication, we have followed the steps which are suggested in [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth) document.

Issue: After getting user info from google server, we may find user or create user depending upon our database result. We stuck after this step, how to proceed further communication to identify user ? should we transfer id_token or own generated api key. The issue with id_token is, it get expired after 3600 or 3900 seconds (not clear).

Following sequence diagram may be helpful to answer.
[image]

Comment: Please consider adding the following tags to your question: php and android.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Thanks for suggestion, added tags as you suggested.